# Why doesn't a.insert(-1, x) mimic a.append(x)?

Tags: python, list, insert, append

So I have the following Python code, which appends numbers 1-10 to the list `values`:

```
values = []

for value in range(1, 11):
    values.append(value)

print(values)
```

And, as expected, gives us `[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]`.

Although impractical, just out of curiosity, I attempted to recreate this result using `insert()` instead of `append()`:

```
values = []

for value in range(1, 11):
    values.insert(-1, value)

print(values)
```

Which gave me the result `[2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 1]`.

I tried this with other ranges as well, and the same thing happens every time: It is in ascending order, except for the smallest number being at the end.

From the [Python Documentation Tutorial](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html), I now know that `a.insert(len(a), x)` can be used to mimic `a.append(x)`. However, I still do not understand why inserting the values to the last position in a list works except for the smallest value.

Comment: One thing to note is that insert function inserts the value at the index and increments the index of all values(on and after the index). So the first insert will be [1](now 1 is at index -1) next will be [2,1] (now 1 is at index -1)then [2,3,1] and so on.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The fundamental thing to understand is that `-1` is not the same as `len(a)`. It is indeed the same as `len(a) - 1`:

```
In [396]: x = [1, 2, 3]

In [397]: x[-1]
Out[397]: 3

In [398]: x[len(x) - 1]
Out[398]: 3
```

When the list has size 1 and more, then `len(a) - 1` will always point to the spot just before the last element (or, technically, to the spot at which the last element currently is), which is where `list.insert` will put your new item.

```
In [400]: x.insert(-1, 4); x
Out[400]: [1, 2, 4, 3]
```

As you've already figured out, `len(a)` points to the spot just after the last element, which is where `list.append` inserts elements. So, `-1`, or `len(a) - 1` will point to the spot of the last element, and `list.insert(-1, ...)` will push the last element to the right, and place the new element in the last element's old position.

Answer (score 1):

When you insert the very first item, the number 1, it is inserted at the exact end of the list because there isn't any other item in the list. Once this has happened, the rest of the inserts occur before the last item of the list, because -1 is the last item of the list and `insert()` inserts before the specified index.

I am actually sort of surprised that `insert()` works at all on an empty list.

Answer (score 1):

I think this happens because `insert` puts in the element right *before* the specified position. So what `a.insert(-1, value)` does is, it puts the `value` right before the last element, and hence becomes the second to last. But when the list is empty, there is no such second to last element and it places it in the last index.

```
>>> a=[]
>>> a.insert(-1, 1)
>>> a
[1] #list is empty so it is inserted in the last index
>>> a.insert(-1, 2)
>>> a
[2, 1] #It placed the 2 on the second to last position, right before the 1
```

Answer (score 0):

That's because `-1` matches the `len(value)-1` or the index of the last item in your list, so if you unpack your `list.insert()` calls your `value` list changes as:

```
[]  # insert(-1, 1) -> -1 translates to -1 (unclear state)
[1]  # insert(-1, 2) -> -1 translates to 0
[2, 1]  # insert(-1, 3) -> -1 translates to 1
[2, 3, 1]  # insert(-1, 4) -> -1 translates to 2
[2, 3, 4, 1]  # insert(-1, 5) -> -1 translates to 3
[2, 3, 4, 5, 1]  # insert(-1, 6) -> -1 translates to 4
[2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 1]  # insert(-1, 7) -> -1 translates to 5
[2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 1]  # insert(-1, 8) -> -1 translates to 6
[2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 1]  # insert(-1, 9) -> -1 translates to 7
[2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 1]  # insert(-1, 10) -> -1 translates to 8
[2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 1]
```